# Python: Resizing widgets when window is resized (Using PLACE manager)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, geometry

After lots of reading, I could not find solution for my problem.

I have made a quiz program using Tkinter and Python. I also used pack geometry manager everywhere. Window is not resizable, it's set to 960x540, and all widgets are precisely set in window using X and Y coordinates. Now, I'd like to make full screen option. But, when I turn it full screen, all  widgets are moved in upper left corner (because they are set to X and Y coordinates using place manager). Any idea how could widgets 'stretch' when I turn window into full screen?
I know this could be accomplished using grid managed, but I would like to use pack manager instead.

I didn't post any code, because I don't think it would help. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

PS: Sorry for my weird English, and thank you a lot!

[image]

Comment: There are many, many ways to accomplish what you want, and the right way depends on exactly what you want the screen to look like. Without seeing the exact layout you want, we can't give a definitive answer. However, `pack` is fairly well documented and it has options for expanding and filling the area it's been given (with the `expand` and `fill` attributes). You should start by reading the documentation and perhaps working through some examples.

Comment: Thank you. Now i have uploaded one image. That's layout (Of one frame. There's several frames with different layouts).

Comment: Have you tried to give relative positions to the `place` method (e.g. `relx=0.5, rely=0.5` to put a widget in the center)?

Comment: It just keep's moving widgets around, Without resizing them.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `grid`? It absolutely is the best tool for this particular job. You can do this with `pack` as well, though it will require the use of a few extra helper frames. You can do it with `place`, but it would be difficult.

Comment: what should happen with all of the space between button 4 and all of the other widgets? Does it just go unused?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use grid you're going to need to use the place manager.  A lot of people recommend against it because it's more complex, but I like the control it gives you over your GUI.

For example you can have a label that always stays in a relative position and has a relative width and height (in relation to the size of the screen)

```
newLabel = tk.Label(root)
newLabel.place(relwidth = 0.5, relheight = 0.2, relx = 0.25, rely = 0.4)
```

This creates a label that is always half the width of the root size, 20% of the root height, and is always centered in the screen.

These are two excellent tutorials on pack and place, and more importantly they are a great reference for the options that pack and place offer (scroll to the bottom of the page to see all the options and their descriptions).  You may be able to get pack to do what you want, but I stick with place.

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm